# Setting up multiple sites correctly

Tags: magento2.3.1, base-url

I'm trying to set up multiple sites for my company.

We want to make it scaleable, so I don't want to touch the default store. I want to create 3 stores, and each one of them needs to have it's own unrelated URL.

Meaning:

http://brand-name-1.com
http://brand-name-2.com
http://brand-name-3.com

What should I use for the default URL? Do I need to buy another url (http://brand-name-0.com) and use that?

I don't want any of the brands to have any relationship on the frontend.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

all you need is to create your store/website in magento, define base url.
add DNS record and point to your ip address.

in nginx or htaccess write store code assigned to your new shop view:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_websites.html

Each website and each store view must have a unique identifier. This identifier is required to use the MAGE_RUN_TYPE and MAGE_RUN_CODE variables.

default url depends on your shop, like GEOip, language, products and other marketing options.